# Embed a file line by line in Combo Box in Python Qt

Tags: python, linux, pyqt4

I am having a situation in which I have to fill `Combo Box` with data available in a file. Mine approach is

```
self.cmbBusListBox.addItem("Select ..")
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('i2coutput.cfg')]
      for line in lines:
            self.cmbBusListBox.addItem(line)
self.cmbBusListBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.selectBusChange)
```

This process giving me error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I2CMain.py", line 3, in <module>
    from Py4 import QtGui, QtCore
ImportError: No module named Py4
```

In any file handling process for data populating from file in `Combo Box` giving same error. 
Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`No module named Py4` but there is one named `PyQt4`:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
```

It's just a typo in import statement and has nothing with combobox populating.